# How do I add up multiple SUMs from different subqueries into one result?

Tags: mysql

How can I add up SUMs from different subqueries in MySQL?

`JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes, customer_id FROM product1_quote GROUP BY customer_id
    ) p1q ON (p1q.customer_id = c.customer_id)`

`JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes, customer_id FROM product2_quote GROUP BY customer_id
    ) p1q ON (p1q.customer_id = c.customer_id)`

So I'd want to add those two up and have numQuotes be the total numQuotes. However, it's a little more complicated than that, because the number of different tables is dynamic, so in any given circumstance there could be any number of subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by changing the JOINs to LEFT JOINs and using `IFNULL(numQuotes".$k.",0)+` inside the PHP loop that puts the queries together, where `$k` is an index.

So the end result is something like:

`SELECT IFNULL(numQuotes0,0)+IFNULL(numQuotes1,0) AS totalQuotes FROM ...`

`LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes0, customer_id FROM product1_quote GROUP BY customer_id ) p1q ON (p1q.customer_id = c.customer_id)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes1, customer_id FROM product2_quote GROUP BY customer_id ) p2q ON (p2q.customer_id = c.customer_id)`

The LEFT JOINs return NULL if no results are found, hence the need for `IFNULL`.

Answer (score 1):

What comes up with the following?

```
select sum(numQuotes), customer_id from
(
  (SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes, customer_id FROM 
  product1_quote GROUP BY customer_id ) p1q ON (p1q.customer_id = c.customer_id)
UNION
  (SELECT SUM(IF(isPurchased='0', 1, 0)) AS numQuotes, customer_id FROM 
  product2_quote GROUP BY customer_id ) p1q ON (p1q.customer_id = c.customer_id)
) group by customer_id;
```

Parentheses might be off so check them first.